# Is it possible to calculate grand total in second gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview

I just want to know. Is it possible to calculate grand total of sub total in second gridview? What I mean is that `GridView2` is in the `GridView1` :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdOne">
   <asp:Gridview ID="grdTwo">
      <---SubTotal--->
      <---Grand Total--->
   </asp:Gridview>
</asp:GridView>
```

Because I have tried many solution, but it is still didn't work.

Comment: If i understood right, the subtotal is in the first grid and you want to show the grand total in the second grid ?

Comment: Nope. The sub total and the grand total in the second grid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you fill the subtotal in a label or a text or you can access it's value while binding so what you got to do is to us the RowDataBound_Event like this:

```
public int sum = 0;

protected void GirdView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {   
        //Sum the value of each subtotal
        sum = sum + subTotalValue;

        //Access the control that you want to to set the GrandTotal in
    }
}
```

If you still don't get the idea, give me in details exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer following link:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/displaying-summary-information-in-the-gridview-s-footer-cs